# How to check if the contents of an entry widget in python/tk is a float, string, boolean or integer?

Tags: python, tk-toolkit

I am trying to check whether users' input to a Tk GUI I created is of the right data type I wanted it to be (integer), but I have only been able to check whether their input is a Boolean, and I need to check whether their input is a string or an integer as well:

```
from tkinter import*

# creates a GUI
Tester = Tk()

NonEssentialFoodEntry = Entry(Tester, width="30")

NonEssentialFoodEntry.place(x=300,y=540)

def checker():
     if NonEssentialFoodEntry.get() == 'TRUE' or 'FALSE':
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror("","You have entered a boolean value in the Non-EssentialFood entry field, please enter an integer")


Checker=Button(Tester, height="7",width="30",font=300,command=checker)

Checker.place(x=700, y=580)
```

Comment: have you tried using `isinstance(value, float)` to verify if the value is a float?

Comment: @akhavro: Can't do that because `Entry`s can only contain sting values.

Comment: The problem is that `1` is a valid integer (number `1`), a valid float (`1.0`), a valid string (`'1'`) and can be implicitely converted to `True` in a boolean context. You are trying to handle the thing the wrong side: do not try to guess what an entry is, just check that it can be converted to the expected type.

Comment: right. Then regex is your solution, as @Jan answered ;)

Comment: user9156115: A common way to do that in Python is to use `try/except` and attempt to convert the string value into each type and see if it works. i.e. something along the line of" `try`, `float(entry.get())`, `except ValueError:`. Note that the order of testing matters because some values might be able to be converted to more that one type.

Comment: Thank you all for you replies!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you *could* run a regular expression on the input and check which group is not `None`:

```
(?:^(?P<boolean>TRUE|FALSE)$)
|
(?:^(?P<integer>\d+)$)
|
(?:^(?P<float>\d+\.\d+)$)
|
(?:^(?P<string>.+)$)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/D7Anur/1/). In the first place, every input is a string though.

---

In `Python`:

```
import re
strings = ["TRUE", "FALSE", "123", "1.234343", "some-string", "some string with numbers and FALSE and 1.23 in it"]

rx = re.compile(r'''
    (?:^(?P<boolean>TRUE|FALSE)$)
    |
    (?:^(?P<integer>-?\d+)$)
    |
    (?:^(?P<float>-?\d+\.\d+)$)
    |
    (?:^(?P<string>.+)$)
    ''', re.VERBOSE)

for string in strings:
    m = rx.search(string)
    instance = [k for k,v in m.groupdict().items() if v is not None]
    print(instance)
    if instance:
        print("{} is probably a(n) {}".format(string, instance[0]))
```

As said in the comments above your original question you might follow another way with `try/except` though.

Answer (score 1):

One approach to this is to try to convert your input and see if it manages.

EDIT: this is basically the approach suggested by @martineau in the comments

The following code is adapted from [FlyingCircus](https://bitbucket.org/norok2/flyingcircus) (**Disclaimer**: of which I am the main author):

```
def auto_convert(
    text,
    casts=(int, float, complex)):
"""
Convert value to numeric if possible, or strip delimiters from string.

Args:
    text (str|int|float|complex): The text input string.
    casts (Iterable[callable]): The cast conversion methods.

Returns:
    val (int|float|complex): The numeric value of the string.

Examples:
    >>> auto_convert('<100>', '<', '>')
    100
    >>> auto_convert('<100.0>', '<', '>')
    100.0
    >>> auto_convert('100.0+50j')
    (100+50j)
    >>> auto_convert('1e3')
    1000.0
    >>> auto_convert(1000)
    1000
    >>> auto_convert(1000.0)
    1000.0
"""
if isinstance(text, str):
    val = None
    for cast in casts:
        try:
            val = cast(text)
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            pass
        else:
            break
    if val is None:
        val = text
else:
    val = text
return val
```

Note that you would need a specialized function for the Boolean case, since `bool(text)` will evaluate to True as soon as `text` is non-empty (which is also present in the latest version of [FlyingCircus](https://bitbucket.org/norok2/flyingcircus) as `flyingcircus.util.to_bool()`).

Answer (score 0):

For instance you could use the following code to build an if-statement around a valid integer:
`if isinstance(<var>, int):`
Otherwise get the type with `type(<var>)` and build your functions around it.